# Alamofire ignores timeoutIntervalForRequest and timeoutIntervalForResource parameters

Tags: swift, alamofire, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I am currently trying to decrease the default values for `timeoutIntervalForRequest` and `timeoutIntervalForResource` of `NSURLSessionConfiguration` for every Alamofire remote calls in my iOS app since I don't want it to wait 60 seconds and 7 days respectively.

This is my code:

```
Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 30

let parameters = [
    "foo": [1,2,3],
    "bar": [
        "baz": "qux"
    ]
]

Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.request(.POST, "someURL", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON) {
    (response) in

    print(response.timeline)
}
```

This is my log:

```
Timeline: { "Latency": 60.977 secs, "Request Duration": 60.977 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.000 secs, "Total Duration": 60.977 secs }
```

As you can see the `Request Duration` value is over 30 seconds.

Does this depends on the fact that I use `Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.request` instead of `Alamofire.request`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1332) on the official Alamofire GitHub page and this was their opinion about that:

> Changing the values of the configuration in a session that's already active has no effect. According to Apple's documentation on `NSURLSession`:
>   `Changing mutable values within the configuration object has no effect on the current session, but you can create a new session with the modified configuration object.`
>
> I suggest you create your manager instance and customize its configuration, as per [our documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#modifying-session-configuration).

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's because you can't change the configuration of the default Manager (or at least I don't think you can, might be a bug).

Try to instance a new one and add a customized NSURLSessionConfiguration.

ex:

```
var manager:Alamofire.Manager?

func initManager(timeoutInterval:Double) {
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = timeoutInterval
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = timeoutInterval

    manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
}

// then use manager!.request to do your request
```